# Adding autocorrelation and heteroscedasticity to i.i.d. time series in R

Tags: r, matlab

here is the background to my question:

I am building a VaR-Model (Value-at-Risk) using semi-parametric marginal distributions and a t-copula.
This approach requires generating i.i.d. time series to correctly estimate the Pareto Tails for the marginal distributions. This is done by using an AR-GARCH model to extract residuals which are i.i.d., then model the marginal distributions and finally generate random numbers which come from a t-copula. I simulate 2000 paths for a time horizon of 22 days. I have 12 securities in my portfolio. I store the random numbers in a 3-dimensional array Z(horizon,paths,security) dim(Z) = 22 2000 12.

Here is my Question:

I would like to reintroduce the original autocorrelation and heteroscedasticity using the coefficients from the AR-GARCH model. MATLAB provides a handy function called 'filter'. This whole idea is not made up by myself but is presented unter the following link (implemented in MATLAB):
[Using Extreme Value Theory and Copulas to Evaluate Market Risk](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/econ/examples/using-extreme-value-theory-and-copulas-to-evaluate-market-risk.html)

Here's the MATLAB code I struggle with to implement in R:

```
simulatedReturns[:,:,i] = filter(fit(i),Z[:,:,i],Y0(i),Z0(i),V0(i))
```

where fit(i) = model coefficients for security i, Z = array with random numbers from t-copula, and Y0, Z0 and V0 are start parameters for returns, standardized residuals and variances, respectively.

In R there is a similar function called `filter` in the package `library(signal)` which does (almost) the same as the MATLAB-function. However, I obtain very dodgy results. I also played around with `ugarchfilter` but was not successful yet.

I have been working with R only for a couple of weeks and not sure if I get the concept wrong or the code.

Many thanks for advice in advance!

Comment: If you don't have specific programming question and are looking for a statistical (tool) advice, I would recommend moving the question over to crossvalidated.com

Comment: ok, thanks for the hint. might fit in better there.